# Command Line 'hls_segment_size' creates TS files with segment failures

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am converting a simple mp4 video to hls but I need the segments to be in approximately a specific size

I researched and found:

```
-hls_segment_size 17000000
```

17000000 bytes(~17MB)

This creates TS files with approximate sizes, (does not have to be exact size)

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "in.mp4" -vcodec copy -acodec aac -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_size 17000000 -f hls "out.m3u8"
```

In the m3u8 file is created '#EXT-X-BYTERANGE', which is the way I want it

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:8.400000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1662108@0
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb0.ts
#EXTINF:4.560000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:383896@0
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb1.ts
#EXTINF:3.120000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:408712@383896
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb1.ts
#EXTINF:5.640000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1161840@0
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb2.ts
#EXTINF:1.880000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:230864@0
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb3.ts
#EXTINF:2.160000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:330880@230864
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb3.ts
#EXTINF:2.080000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:489928@0
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb4.ts
#EXTINF:4.400000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1564348@489928
SampleVideo_1280x720_30mb4.ts
...
```

It seems alright, but it has a little problem. I'm testing on a player in the browser, and when the seconds goes from one segment to the other the video has a lock in sound and video. Something very annoying, not natural in the video.

Not using '-hls_segment_size' will have functional TS files, and without BYTERANGE in the m3u8 file

However, the size of the TS file will be according to the seconds defined

I am currently trying to get a ts file that is close to a size set between 15MB and 20MB, and have BYTERANGE in the m3u8 file.

Does anyone have any ideas?

here's the problem I'm trying to describe:

http://phantsc.rf.gd/AAA/Bbb.html

exactly in the second 7 of the video a 'locking' happens, this happens when going from one segment to another

Comment: This seems difficult to me, there is no one who can help ...

Comment: check if your server is correctly configured to handle HTTP range requests. The sample using `hls.js` shows responses with status `200` instead of `206` for the `.ts` files even if the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header is present. You seem to get the entire segment in the response instead of the required range, based on `Content-Length`.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your ffmpeg version into > 4
Old version is buggy for this command.

Comment: Can you add some links or additional info to clarify?